# Success message doesn't show in my custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, success-message

I have created custom success message which would be shown after the form submission. I have enabled full page cache is backend now that message is not showing.

So, I changed `cachable="false"` for that template but not working find the code below,

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="page.messages">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content" cacheable="false">
        <block class="Customer\Form\Block\Index\Form" name="form_index_form" template="Customer_Form::form_index_form.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: @Prince Patel,i am facing same issue in custom checkout module can you help here please https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275067/how-to-enable-error-messages-this-messagemanager-adderror-error-in-c?noredirect=1#comment391995_275067

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try below code,changed is only adding cacheable="false" in block 

<body>
    <referenceContainer name="page.messages">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Customer\Form\Block\Index\Form" name="form_index_form" template="Customer_Form::form_index_form.phtml" cacheable="false" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Hope it will help you.

Also read Magento Doc http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html

Comment: i am facing same problem in custom checkout step,because we are using fragmented url like: SiteUrl/checkout/#cart     so it's not triggering error messages

Comment: can you please help here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275067/how-to-enable-error-messages-this-messagemanager-adderror-error-in-c?noredirect=1#comment391995_275067

Comment: cacheable="false" not worked in my case