# How to enable Error Messages $this->_messageManager->addError(__('Error')); in Custom Checkout Module Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom, frontend-error

> app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Theme\templates\messages.phtml

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'messages'">
        <div data-bind="foreach: { data: cookieMessages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
            <div data-bind="attr: {
                class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
                'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
            }">
                <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="foreach: { data: messages().messages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
            <div data-bind="attr: {
                class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
                'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
            }">
                <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                            "messages": {
                                "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    </script>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <head>
        <title>Multi Step Checkout</title>
    </head> 

    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <referenceBlock name="messages">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument xsi:type="string" name="template">Magento_Theme::messages.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>     
        </referenceContainer>

        <container name="sidebar.additional" label="Sidebar Additional" htmlTag="div">
            <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true" />         
        </container>


        <referenceBlock name="content">

        </referenceBlock>   


    </body>
</page>
```

> In Controller Code

```
$errorMsg = "Something";
$this->_messageManager->addError(__($errorMsg));
$this->_redirect('checkout', ['_fragment' => 'cart']);
```

> But Even after all It's not triggering Error Messages.

[image]

Comment: have you checked success message is displaying?

Comment: @prashant valanda, it's not displaying any success or error message

Comment: @All,please check the link , it's worked for me. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7561#issuecomment-432606764

Comment: @PrashantValanda i solved this error issue in locals server but in live server it's not firing any messages even it's not displaying any error messages on default checkout page also

Comment: @PrashantValanda can you please check  my updated question some console error is there in our checkout page,is this issue may be causing due to this console errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code worked for me
>
> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="content">        
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

> app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Theme\templates\messages.phtml

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'messages'">
        <div data-bind="foreach: { data: cookieMessages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
            <div data-bind="attr: {
                class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
                'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
            }">
                <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="foreach: { data: messages().messages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
            <div data-bind="attr: {
                class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
                'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
            }">
                <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                            "messages": {
                                "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    </script>
```